# Accessing parent variables in child method

Tags: php, class, scope, private-members

I currently have two classes, one called Dog, one called Poodle. Now how can I use a variable defined in Dog from the Poodle class. My code is as follows:

```
  class dog {
       protected static $name = '';

       function __construct($name) {
            $this->name = $name
       }
  }

  class Poodle extends dog {
       function __construct($name) {
           parent::__construct($name)
       } 

       function getName(){
           return parent::$name;
       }
  }

$poodle = new Poodle("Benjy");
print $poodle->getName();
```

I get this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: name

Comment: don't u need to inherit?

Comment: Oooops sorry guys, i missed that little bit out of my code when i was posting it on here. it still doesnt work with extends in

Answer (score 5):

i guess 'name' is an attribute of the concrete Dog, so it shouldn't be static in the first place. To access non-static parent class attributes from within an inherited class, just use "$this".

```
    class dog {
       protected $name = '';

       function __construct($name) {
            $this->name = $name;
       }
    }

    class Poodle extends dog {
       function getName(){
           return $this->name;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `Dog` constructor.  You wrote:

```
$this->name = $name;
```

But using `$this` implies that `name` is an *instance* variable, when in fact it's a *static* variable.  Change it to this:

```
self::$name = $name;
```

That should work fine.

Comment: However it doesn't make much sense to have all (inherented) instances of dog to have the same name, so static doesn't make much sense here.

Answer (score 0):

In your dog class you have declared the variable $name as **static**, you have to declare the variable without the static word

```
class dog {
   protected $name = '';

   function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name
   }
}



class Poodle extends dog {
   function __construct($name) {
       parent::__construct($name)
   } 

   function getName(){
       return $this->name;
   }
}

$poodle = new Poodle("Benjy");
print $poodle->getName();
```